# Animate an image view in Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I need to make an image view animate it's self on and off of the screen. I want it to be when the user taps the screen the image slides up. Is there a relatively easy way to smoothly move the image view?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an animation block, e.g.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slide-up" context:NULL];
imageView.center = CGPointMake(200, -100);  // change this to somewhere else you want.
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

See the [*iPhone Application Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW11) for detail.